# Generic pointer to point to different class templates

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I have a template class as shown.

```
template <class T>
class CValueEdit : public TextAreaWithOneWildcard
{
public:
CValueEdit() : m_bIsSelected(false)
{
    m_Value = (T)0;
    m_Step = (T)1;
    m_MaxBoundary = (T)1;
    m_MinBoundary = (T)0;

}
void setBoundaryValues(T max, T min)
{
    m_MaxBoundary = max;
    m_MinBoundary = min;
}
void setValue(T value)
{
    m_Value = value;
}
void setStep(T step)
{
    m_Step = step;
}
void incrementValue() // ++ operator overloading can be used here
{
    m_Value += m_Step;
}
void decrementValue() // -- operator overloading can be used here
{
    m_Value -= m_Step;
}
void getValue(T& ref_Value)
{
    ref_Value = m_Value;
}
virtual void handleClickEvent()
{
    m_bIsSelected = true;
}
bool isSelected()
{
    return m_bIsSelected;
}

~CValueEdit(){}

private:

T m_Value, m_MaxBoundary, m_MinBoundary, m_Step;
bool m_bIsSelected;


};
```

I am using this class to store a value which may be float or int.
TextAreaWithOneWildCard is a widget class for Touch sensitive Application .
There will be more than one ValueEdit objects in a window.

eg :

```
ValueEdit<float> m_pressure[3];
ValueEdit<int> m_time[3];
```

I need to register the address of the touched widget in parent window.

For that I need a generic pointer that can point to either `ValueEdit<float>` or `ValueEdit<int>` . How can I declare that pointer?

If user touches one widget I want this widget to register pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should register a pointer to an `TextAreaWithOneWildcard`. Then there is something missing: what will you do with this pointer? If you need to call e.g `setValue(T value)` then you can expose somehow  `TextAreaWithOneWildcard` type (for example with a dedicated method) and use a dynamic_cast.

Something along this line:

```
class CValueEditBase : public TextAreaWithOneWildcard
{
public:
    enum type_e {int_e, float_e} ;
    virtual type_e type(void) const = 0 ; 
}
```

and then

```
template <class T>
class CValueEdit : public CValueEditBase 
{
public:
    virtual type_e type(void) const { return std::is_integral<T>::value ? int_e : float_e) ; }
...
} ;
```